# Evolution simulator: TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python

I'm trying to make an evolution simulator but the program keeps throwing me this error "TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment". The program is suppose to create two random creatures, then give them a random mutation and print the value of the creatures. With some fiddling I've gotten it to throws an error, print only the first creature, or print both creatures without the mutation. Any help?

```
import random
from random import randint

creatures = (random.randint(1, 10), random.randint(1, 10))


print(creatures)

for i in creatures:
    randomMutation = random.randint(1, 2)
    creatures[i] = i + randomMutation

for i in range(newEvolution):
    print("New evolution", newEvolution)
```

newEvolution should be a list of creatures with the added mutation.

Comment: Tuples are immutable, use a list instead

Comment: newEvolution is not defined anywhere, I don't understand your code.

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty straight forward. [Tuples do not support item assignment](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences): they are immutable. Use a list, instead.

> Tuples are immutable, and usually contain a heterogeneous sequence of elements that are accessed via unpacking (see later in this section) or indexing (or even by attribute in the case of namedtuples).

Correct code:

```
import random
from random import randint

creatures = [random.randint(1, 10), random.randint(1, 10)]

print(creatures)

for index, value in enumerate(creatures):
    randomMutation = random.randint(1, 2)
    creatures[index] = value + randomMutation
```

Answer (score 0):

Creatures are tuple and you are trying to assign them by
Creatures[i]=i+randomMutation
Which is not possible in case of tuples as they are immutable please use list as suggested by fedeisas